# Call windows exe file from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, exe

I am calling exe file from rails application.I have set-up rails application over windows machine and from code I am running exe file.In this I need to pass a path in the arguments.

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
xml_file_path = @project.xml_file_name
basename = File.basename(xml_file_path) i.e "12.xml"
```

Tried this -

```
final_xml_path = "C:\Windows\System32\workspace\preference\public\xml_files\#{basename}"
```

I have tried this -

```
 final_xml_path = 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\workspace\\preference\\public\\xml_files\\#{basename}'
```

Output - p final_xml_path

```
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\workspace\\preference\\public\\xml_files\\\#{basename}"
```

Desired output -

```
final_xml_path = "C:\Windows\System32\workspace\preference\public\xml_files\12.xml"
```

I need this output I need to pass in the arguments while running exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple [join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/File.html#method-c-join) is all you need:

```rb
final_xml_path = File.join('C:\Windows\System32\', basename)
```

Comment: 'C:\Windows\System32\'  there is back slash in the last which doesn't close the brackets. I have already tried it.

Comment: Remove it, it's not necessary.

Comment: If I will remove this then that will be syntax error.

Comment: What? I mean, remove the trailing backslash: `final_xml_path = File.join('C:\Windows\System32', 'afile.xml')`

Answer (score 0):

Managed the path in the exe file and then send called the exe with just basename.

```
final_xml_path =`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/workspace/csharp-code/Namantest1.exe #{basename}`
```

I got the desired result.